# SELECT sql statement with two different tables and condition

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Having two tables in my database, it's like

Department

```
//Department
D#      DNAME
---------------
1      RESEARCH
2        IT
3       SCIENCE
```

PROJECT

```
//Project
Budget      D#
---------------
22500       1
22300       1
50000       2
```

So i using this statement

```
SELECT D#,DNAME and sum(budget) as total budget
    FROM DEPARTMENT,PROJECT
GROUP BY D#;
```

my output should be like, if a department don't have any project budget mean display 0

```
D#      DNAME      total budget
-------------------------------
1       RESEARCH      44800
2          IT         50000
3        SCIENCE        0
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing your `where` clause:

```
SELECT d.D#,DNAME and sum(budget) as total budget
FROM DEPARTMENT d, PROJECT p
where d.d# = p.dt#
GROUP BY d.D#;
```

Or to include departments without budget:

```
SELECT d.D#,DNAME and sum(budget) as total budget
FROM DEPARTMENT d
left outer join PROJECT p
on d.d# = p.d#
GROUP BY d.D#;
```

Comment: @user3553846: need more help or was this answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```
   SELECT `D#`,`DNAME`, 
   IFNULL((SELECT sum(`budget`) 
          FROM `project` WHERE `project.`D#` = `Department`.`D#` ),0) AS `total budget` 
   FROM `Department`
```

If you execute `EXPLAIN` on this query, you might notice, that it uses indexes more efficient then queries with `GROUP BY`